# C++ error expected ' ' or '...' before numeric constant

Tags: c++

Noob ask

```
void setName(const std::string& InkClient) { m_appName = InkClient; }
void setCompactName(const std::string& InkClient) { m_appCompactName = InkClient; }
void setVersion(const std::string& 0.1) { m_appVersion = 0.1 ; }
```

I dont know how i can fix

void setVersion(const std::string& 0.1) { m_appVersion = 0.1 ; }

Comment: `0.1` is not a valid variable name, so `const std::string& 0.1` is not a valid parameter declaration.

Comment: `const std::string& 0.1` - what is that supposed to mean???

Answer (score 4):

```
const std::string& 0.1
```

0.1 is actually a constant. A valid variable name is expected.
If you don't need that argument for anything else, just remove it (leave brackets empty). If the function must take a parameter of type string by reference, just remove the constant. An argument with no name is not used by the function; however, it allows for dealing with compatibility issues.
To keep the parameter usable, try the following:

```
void setVersion(const std::string& version) {m_appVersion = version;}
```

where `version` can be any valid variable name.

I hope this helps! :D